# Check if class is a subclass of another class

Tags: swift

How can I check if a class is a subclass of another class using types only, without objects?

Something like:

```
class SuperClass {}
class SubClass: SuperClass {}

SuperClass.self == SubClass.self // should return true, but it returns false
```

Comment: `SubClass is SuperClass` ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why do you need this? I had never the need to do this and maybe if we know the 'why' we can help.

Comment: Although I don't know why you need this, but [It **is** possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63694904/5623035)

Comment: Why would `SuperClass.self == SubClass.self` in this example? That definitely is not true. You cannot use SuperClass everywhere you can use SubClass. They are not equal.

Comment: You could do `SubClass.self is SuperClass.Type`, which compiles and seems to do what you want, but I'm not sure how useful it is since it's always true (and produces a warning about it always being true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes should inherit from the `NSObject`. Then you can check that like:

```
import Foundation

class SuperClass: NSObject { }
class SubClass: SuperClass { }

SubClass.isSubclass(of: SuperClass.self) // Returns true
```